# Resizing column width on a table

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently, I am able to resize the columns of a table if the width of the table is no bigger than the width of the container.

What I would like to happen is for the width of the table to grow, when resizing the columns, so that a scroll bar appears below the table. Basically allowing me to resize without the limitation of the width of the container.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/u5bvwh8m/7/

Code Snippet

```js
//var tables = document.getElementsByClassName('flexiCol');
var tables = document.getElementsByClassName('resizable');
for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
  resizableGrid(tables[i]);
}

function resizableGrid(table) {
  var row = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0],
    cols = row ? row.children : undefined;
  if (!cols) return;

  table.style.overflow = 'hidden';

  var tableHeight = table.offsetHeight;

  for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
    var div = createDiv(tableHeight);
    cols[i].appendChild(div);
    cols[i].style.position = 'relative';
    setListeners(div);
  }

  function setListeners(div) {
    var pageX, curCol, nxtCol, curColWidth, nxtColWidth;

    div.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
      curCol = e.target.parentElement;
      nxtCol = curCol.nextElementSibling;
      pageX = e.pageX;

      var padding = paddingDiff(curCol);

      curColWidth = curCol.offsetWidth - padding;
      if (nxtCol)
        nxtColWidth = nxtCol.offsetWidth - padding;
    });

    div.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
      e.target.style.borderRight = '2px solid #0000ff';
    })

    div.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
      e.target.style.borderRight = '';
    })

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
      if (curCol) {
        var diffX = e.pageX - pageX;

        if (nxtCol)
          nxtCol.style.width = (nxtColWidth - (diffX)) + 'px';

        curCol.style.width = (curColWidth + diffX) + 'px';
      }
    });

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
      curCol = undefined;
      nxtCol = undefined;
      pageX = undefined;
      nxtColWidth = undefined;
      curColWidth = undefined
    });
  }

  function createDiv(height) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.top = 0;
    div.style.right = 0;
    div.style.width = '5px';
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.style.cursor = 'col-resize';
    div.style.userSelect = 'none';
    div.style.height = height + 'px';
    return div;
  }

  function paddingDiff(col) {

    if (getStyleVal(col, 'box-sizing') == 'border-box') {
      return 0;
    }

    var padLeft = getStyleVal(col, 'padding-left');
    var padRight = getStyleVal(col, 'padding-right');
    return (parseInt(padLeft) + parseInt(padRight));

  }

  function getStyleVal(elm, css) {
    return (window.getComputedStyle(elm, null).getPropertyValue(css))
  }
};
```

```html
<style>
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  td,
  th {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    text-align: left;
  }

  table,
  th,
  td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }

</style>

<table id="tableId" class="resizable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" /></th>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th>File</th>
      <th>File2</th>
      <th>File3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>10Mb</td>
      <td>C:\Users\BrainBell\Desktop\Empty\abc.txt</td>
      <td>C:\Users\BrainBell\Desktop\Empty\abc.txt</td>
      <td>C:\Users\BrainBell\Desktop\Empty\abc.txt</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6):

Managed to solve this by updating the table width on mousemove: https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/u5bvwh8m/16/

```
document.getElementById('tableId').style.width = tableWidth + diffX + "px"
```

Full Code:

```js
//var tables = document.getElementsByClassName('flexiCol');
var tables = document.getElementsByClassName('resizable');
for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
  resizableGrid(tables[i]);
}

function resizableGrid(table) {
  var row = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0],
    cols = row ? row.children : undefined;
  if (!cols) return;

  table.style.overflow = 'hidden';

  var tableHeight = table.offsetHeight;

  for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
    var div = createDiv(tableHeight);
    cols[i].appendChild(div);
    cols[i].style.position = 'relative';
    setListeners(div);
  }

  function setListeners(div) {
    var pageX, curCol, nxtCol, curColWidth, nxtColWidth, tableWidth;

    div.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) { 
    
     tableWidth = document.getElementById('tableId').offsetWidth;
      curCol = e.target.parentElement;
      nxtCol = curCol.nextElementSibling;
      pageX = e.pageX;

      var padding = paddingDiff(curCol);

      curColWidth = curCol.offsetWidth - padding;
    //  if (nxtCol)
        //nxtColWidth = nxtCol.offsetWidth - padding;
    });

    div.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
      e.target.style.borderRight = '2px solid #0000ff';
    })

    div.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
      e.target.style.borderRight = '';
    })

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
      if (curCol) {
        var diffX = e.pageX - pageX;

       // if (nxtCol)
          //nxtCol.style.width = (nxtColWidth - (diffX)) + 'px';

        curCol.style.width = (curColWidth + diffX) + 'px'; 
        document.getElementById('tableId').style.width = tableWidth + diffX + "px"
      }
    });

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
      curCol = undefined;
      nxtCol = undefined;
      pageX = undefined;
      nxtColWidth = undefined;
      curColWidth = undefined
    });
  }

  function createDiv(height) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.top = 0;
    div.style.right = 0;
    div.style.width = '5px';
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.style.cursor = 'col-resize';
    div.style.userSelect = 'none';
    div.style.height = height + 'px';
    return div;
  }

  function paddingDiff(col) {

    if (getStyleVal(col, 'box-sizing') == 'border-box') {
      return 0;
    }

    var padLeft = getStyleVal(col, 'padding-left');
    var padRight = getStyleVal(col, 'padding-right');
    return (parseInt(padLeft) + parseInt(padRight));

  }

  function getStyleVal(elm, css) {
    return (window.getComputedStyle(elm, null).getPropertyValue(css))
  }
};
```

```html
<style>
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  td,
  th {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    text-align: left;
  }

  table,
  th,
  td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }

</style>

<table id="tableId" class="resizable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" /></th>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th>File</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>10Mb</td>
      <td>C:\Usabc.txt</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Simple and does the job, but I'd lose the table width override.

Comment: Awesome. Rocking Solution

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Bootstrap-table out there I was able to call thatOneGuy's function from the onPostHeader Event.

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
    onPostHeader: function () {
        var tables = document.getElementsByClassName('resizable');
        for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
            resizableGrid(tables[i]);
        }
        return false;
    },
});
```