# add & remove/resize width of multiple columns

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the below code. the goal is to be able to resize the columns by mousedown event and drag left/right on the black "border" columns. How do I do the actual addition/subtraction and figure out the direction the mouse is being moved?

```js
document.getElementById('border1').onmousedown = function() {
  alert('add/remove width on col one/two');
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.col,.border{
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom:100px;
}
.one{
  background-color: #2a85ff;
  width:18%;
}
.two{
  background-color: #83bf6e;
  width:18%;
}
.border{
  background-color:#000000;
  width:5px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="col one" id="col1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="border" id="border1">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="col two" id="col2">
    2
  </div>
```

Comment: You should add relevant informations or reduce the amount of code provided (ex 3 or 4  cols instead of 5) instead of adding useless text.

Comment: If you select the border between `col1` and `col2`, wich col is supposed to expand ? If it's the first one, then how do you expand the 5th one ? These could be usefull informations you could add

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resizing column width on a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58660470/resizing-column-width-on-a-table)

Comment: @Cédric I have updated the question per your suggestion.

Comment: @James maybe. i will try, but its table cells not div. maybe will work the same. :)